# Using JavaScript with JSF and Facelets

Tags: javascript, jsf, facelets

I would like to use JavaScript to manipulate hidden input fields in a JSF/Facelets page. When the page loads, I need to set a hidden field to the color depth of the client.

From my Facelet:

```
<body onload="setColorDepth(document.getElementById(?????);">

<h:form>
  <h:inputHidden value="#{login.colorDepth}" id="colorDepth" />
</h:form>
```

When JSF processes the page, it is of course changing the IDs of the elements. What's the best way to reference these elements from my JavaScript code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to set the ID of the form so you'll know what it is. Then you'll be able to construct the actual element ID.

```
<body onload="setColorDepth(document.getElementById('myForm:colorDepth');">

<h:form id="myForm">
  <h:inputHidden value="#{login.colorDepth}" id="colorDepth" />
</h:form>
```

If you don't want to set the form's ID field, you could find it at runtime, like so:

```
<body onload="setColorDepth(document.getElementById(document.forms[0].id + ':colorDepth');">
```

Comment: is it not possibly to be more dynamic here?

Answer (score 0):

View the generated html source and look at what the jsf named the id attribute of the tag.

You will soon see how the naming convention works.  Its usually like FORMNAME:FIELDNAME

Comment: This is a bit dangerous as the generated ID may change unexpectedly. For example, it'll change if a JSF element is added before the form element.

Comment: This is why the best practice is to always name your components. In this case he has id="colorDepth". The form should also have a set name as well. It will only change if he changes it. Or adds a new form before this form. Such are the pitfalls of faces development.

Comment: [I've answered this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045307/how-can-i-know-the-id-of-a-jsf-component-so-i-can-use-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the control's *clientId* as returned by [UIComponent.getClientId(FacesContext)](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.1_01/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId(javax.faces.context.FacesContext)). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265175/how-does-jsf-generate-the-name-of-the-form-input-field#265561) for sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function findElement globally and use it everywhere

```
function findElement(elementId) {
        if(document.getElementById(elementId)) return elementId;
        for(var  i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
            if(document.getElementById(document.forms[i].id + ':' + elementId)) {
                return document.forms[i].id + ':' + elementId;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    <body onload="setColorDepth(findElement('colorDepth'));">
```

Comment: [I've answered this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045307/how-can-i-know-the-id-of-a-jsf-component-so-i-can-use-in-javascript)