# Where does the ID like "pbG62d78562_2d4676_2d4b22_2d96b8_2d227d65ceaa9f_j_id1" come from?

Tags: javascript, jsf, facelets

I'm working with JavaScript and Facelets page,

here my code:

```
<h:head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function transfer() {
            alert(editor.getMolfile());
            document.getElementById("strMol").value = editor.getMolfile();

            var newVal=document.getElementById("strMol").value;
            alert("new val"+newVal);
        }
    </script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="searchMoleculeForm">
        <h:inputHidden name="strMol" id="strMol" value="#{search.strMol}" />
        <rich:panel >
            <f:facet name="header">
                Search The Molecule
            </f:facet>
            <center>
                <div id="editor"></div>
            </center>
            <center>
                <h:commandButton value="substructure" action="#{search.subStructure}" onclick="transfer();" />
                <h:commandButton value="exact_similar" action="#{search.exactSearch}" onclick="transfer();" />
                <h:commandButton value="pharmacophore" action="#{search.pharmacore}" onclick="transfer();" />
                <h:commandButton value="shape" action="#{search.shapeSearch}" onclick="transfer();" />
            </center>
        </rich:panel>
    </h:form>
    <script type='text/JavaScript'>
        var editor = chemwriter.loadEditor('editor');
    </script>
</h:body>
```

it not working, and when I view source code, other id coming with the id "strMol" something like this:

```
<input id="pbG62d78562_2d4676_2d4b22_2d96b8_2d227d65ceaa9f_j_id1:searchMoleculeForm:strMol" type="hidden"
```

so I put that ID inside

```
document.getElementById("pbG62d78562_2d4676_2d4b22_2d96b8_2d227d65ceaa9f_j_id1:searchMoleculeForm:strMol")
```

and it started to work..

my question is, where the other ID id coming? how i can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I already solve this problem by refer to this link [How can I know the id of a JSF component so I can use in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045307/how-can-i-know-the-id-of-a-jsf-component-so-i-can-use-in-javascript)

i just put

```
 document.getElementById("#{strMol.clientId}").value =  editor.getMolfile();
```

and here i add binding inside tag

```
<h:inputHidden id="strMol" value="#{search.strMol}" binding="#{strMol}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Given that I see a `<rich:panel>` tag, I assume you are using [`RichFaces`](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces), an implementation of JSF. That id is automatically generated by the framework. You can read a bit about the logic behind that [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.de/2009/10/jsf-working-with-component-identifiers.html). Fixing that depends on what you mean by fixing.

Comment: This ID is not coming from the JSF component. OP is using a portlet.

Comment: sorry for not mention above, yes, i using richface + portlet, so how can i solve this problem?