# document.querySelector multiple data-attributes in one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, element

I'm trying to find an element with `document.querySelector` which has *multiple data-attributes*:

```
<div class="text-right" data-point-id="7febe088-4eca-493b-8455-385b39ad30e3" data-period="current">-</div>
```

I thought about something like this:

```
document.querySelector('[data-point-id="7febe088-4eca-493b-8455-385b39ad30e3"] [data-period="current"]')
```

But it does not work. 
However, it works well, if I put the second data-attribute in a child-element like:

```
<div class="text-right" data-point-id="7febe088-4eca-493b-8455-385b39ad30e3"> <span data-period="current">-</span> </div>
```

So, is there an option to search for **both attributes at once**?
I've tried several options but I don't get it.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

There should not be a space between the 2 selectors

```
document.querySelector('[data-point-id="7febe088-4eca-493b-8455-385b39ad30e3"][data-period="current"]')
```

if you give a space between them it will become a [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors), ie it will search for an element attribute `data-period="current"` which is inside an element with `data-point-id="7febe088-4eca-493b-8455-385b39ad30e3"` like

```
<div class="text-right" data-point-id="7febe088-4eca-493b-8455-385b39ad30e3">
    <div data-period="current">-</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TamásMárton That's not correct. "So, a valid unquoted attribute value in CSS is any string of text that is not the empty string, is not just a hyphen (-), consists of escaped characters and/or characters matching /[-_\u00A0-\u10FFFF]/ entirely, and doesn’t start with a digit or two hyphens or a hyphen followed by a digit." https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values#css

Comment: @yckart I wrote it based on an a Firefox observation which I repeated many times. But it seems I either messed up something or bumped into a bug, because the selector works properly with unquoted attribute values now. Thanks for pointing out. (For the record: I deleted my misleading, unnecessary comment.)

Answer (score 10):

space in selector looks for `[data-period="current"]` in`[data-point-id="7febe088-4eca-493b-8455-385b39ad30e3"]` .You don't need to put space in between attribute value selector:

```
document.querySelector('[data-point-id="7febe088-4eca-493b-8455-385b39ad30e3"][data-period="current"]')
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I came up with a solution for selecting a specific class by multiple dataset attributes.

```
document.querySelector('.text-right[data-point-id="7febe088-4eca-493b-8455-385b39ad30e3"][data-period="current"]')
```

What you thought was correct, however you just needed to specify the class you were trying to select.