# Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'button[data-id="purple-button" disabled]' is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, html, jestjs, puppeteer, queryselector

How do I query for an element with multiple attributes?  I.E. I want to select the element based on its element type, data-id, and whether it is `disabled` or not.

Here is the html:

`<button disabled="" data-id="purple-button">...</button>`

and here is my test code:

```
await page.evaluate(
    () => document.querySelector('button[data-id="purple-button" disabled]') !== null,
  );
```

The error when I try running the test is the title of this post.  I have tried looking at other solutions on stackoverflow but have not found any yet that use examples of elements with multiple attributes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `document.querySelector('button[data-id="purple-button"]')` forget disabled attribute, it's not signifiant

Comment: Thanks @MisterJojo, but it is important to me that the button is disabled.  Is there a way to check that too?

Comment: forget disabled attribute, it's not signifiant ,a button with no disabled attribute will always return false on a disabled test

Comment: Feels like you want to get an array of some elements perhaps? I would suggest once you get the matches that you `.filter()`  those for "disabled" perhaps? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use brackets to separate the attributes.

```
document.querySelector('button[data-id="purple-button"][disabled]')
```

Per [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29937844/10376309)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!  And welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when a button is disabled it has an "aria-label" or something that changes when a button goes to enabled -> disabled.

This is how I usually check when a pageable button has reached the end.

```
document.querySelector('button[data-id="purple-button"').getAttribute("aria-label") == "disabled"
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues with your code so I include that as well.

Use caution with those `disabled=`, see here for example where I get a node list then filter them to get those that are disabled.

Note you can also leverage the `.length` as a boolean with a `!!`, so I included that example as well (not your `!== null;` thing)

```js
let purples = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-id="purple-button"]');
console.log("p:", purples.length);
let purplesDisabled = Array.prototype.filter.call(purples, function(el) {
  return el.disabled;
});
console.log("p:", purples.length, "pD:", purplesDisabled.length, !!purplesDisabled.length);

let greens = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-id="green-button"]');
console.log("p:", greens.length);
let greensDisabled = Array.prototype.filter.call(greens, function(el) {
  return el.disabled;
});
console.log("g:", greens.length, "gD:", greensDisabled.length, "Boolean:", !!greensDisabled.length);
```

```html
<button disabled data-id="purple-button">...</button>
<button disabled data-id="purple-button">...</button>
<button data-id="purple-button">...</button>
<button disabled="fred" data-id="purple-button">...</button>
<button disabled=false data-id="purple-button">Nope, it is disabled</button>
<button disabled="false" data-id="purple-button">Not Really NOT disabled</button>

<button data-id="green-button">...</button>
<button data-id="green-button">...</button>
<button data-id="green-button">...</button>
```