# Focus on first cell at Primefaces rowedit

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, focus

I have rowEdit just like this: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml

after click at pencil i have to focused input "id". Any ideas?

```
<p:rowEditor onclick="setFocus()">
...
</p:rowEditor>


<f:facet name="input">
    <p:calendar id="startShiftFocus" value="#{oneRow.startShift}" locale="cs" pattern="#{i18n['dateTimeFormat']}" showOn="" timeOnly="true"></p:calendar>
</f:facet>




function setFocus(){
      document.getElementById("startShiftFocus").focus();
      }
```

Comment: read about id vs clientId: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045307/how-can-i-know-the-id-of-a-jsf-component-so-i-can-use-in-javascript

Comment: THX a lot, it works!!