# How to select a JSF generated html element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf, jsf-2

In my JSF application,one of the html element having the below ID.

```
FrmOffer:rptOffer:0:j_idt325:0:j_idt355:0:j_idt356:0:j_idt560:0:j_idt632
```

When I try to select the element using below Jquery lines,

**Option 1:**
**$('#FrmOffer:rptOffer:0:j_idt325:0:j_idt355:0:j_idt356:0:j_idt560:0:j_idt632');**

*This returns :*
    Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognised expression: unsupported pseudo: rptOffer

**Option 2:**

```
$('#FrmOffer\\:rptOffer\\:0\\:j_idt325\\:0\\:j_idt355\\:0\\:j_idt356\\:0\\:j_idt560:0\\:j_idt632');
```

*This returns:*
[]

Can anyone advice how to select the element ?

Comment: you can use start with selector like `$('[id^=FrmOffer]').length`

Answer (score 0):

That way you gonna suffer.

In jsf you can reffer to elements concatenating their parent element's name, if all the elements have an Id:

```
<h:form id="formId">
    <h:inputText id="emailAddresses" value="#{emailAddresses.emailAddressesStr}"/>
```

`var input = document.getElementById('formId:emailAddress');`

Maybe that answered question could help you [How can I know the id of a JSF component so I can use in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045307/how-can-i-know-the-id-of-a-jsf-component-so-i-can-use-in-javascript)

Comment: I already referred the link, but If I add ID to the parent element, the I have to modify the code of all the child elements. I don't want to break the functionality of such a complex for the sake of the one small change.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the native javascript selector instead of jquery. 
*Below is my code:*

```
document.getElementById('FrmOffer:rptOffer:0:j_idt325:0:j_idt355:0:j_idt356:0:j_idt560:0:j_idt632');
```