# Unable to set focus on p:inputText in dataTable

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I'm providing a button to add new inputText inside a cellEditor in a dataTable. 
I would like to set focus on this new inputText automatically (after clicking the button) such that the user may begin entering data without having to first click on the cell. 
My code looks like this:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{myBean.addNewKeyword}" oncomplete="setFocus();" value="New keyword" onclick="editKeywords();" update='keywordForm' icon="fa fa-plus" />

<p:dataTable id="editKeywordsTbl" value="#{myBean.currentListKeywords}" var="keyWd" editMode="cell" editable="true" resizableColumns="true" widgetVar="editKeywords" rowIndexVar="index" >

    <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{myBean.onCellEditKeywords}" update="form" />
        <p:column headerText="Keyword" width="80">
            <p:cellEditor>
                 <f:facet name="output">
                      <h:outputText value="#{keyWd.keyword}" />
                 </f:facet>
                 <f:facet name="input">
                     <p:inputText value="#{keyWd.keyword}" placeholder="click here to edit" />
                 </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

I tried to set the fokus on the last inputText with javascript:

```
function setFocus() {
    var myTable = document.getElementById('editKeywordsTbl');
    var inputs = myTable.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var elemLast = inputs[inputs.length - 1];
    elemLast.focus();
};
```

Unfortunately this's not working!
I should maybe mention, that this is happening inside a dialog.
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

**For clarification:** My problem is not getting the id of the inputText.
With my Javascript, I have access to this element and so I can get the id.

**Edit:**
I tried `elemLast.click();` in my javascript. The new inputText is open for edit and has focus for a second and then get lost. 
I don't understand why is this happening.
**Edit2 - Minimal reproducible example:**
The Xhtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        Hello from Facelets
        <br />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function setFocus() {
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    var myTable = document.getElementById('editKeywordsTbl');
                    var inputs = myTable.getElementsByTagName('input');

                    var elemLast = inputs[inputs.length - 1];
                    console.log("elemLast: " + elemLast.id);
                    elemLast.click();
                    elemLast.focus();
                });
            }
        </script>

        <h:form id="keywordForm" prependId="false" >

            <p:commandButton action="#{myBean.addNewKeyword}" oncomplete="setFocus();" value="New keyword" update='keywordForm' />
            <br /><br /><br/>

            <p:dataTable id="editKeywordsTbl" value="#{myBean.currentListKeywords}" var="keyWd" editMode="cell" editable="true" resizableColumns="true" widgetVar="editKeywords" rowIndexVar="index" >

                <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{myBean.onCellEditKeywords}" />

                <p:column headerText="Keyword" width="80">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="[click me to edit]" rendered="#{keyWd.name == ''}" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{keyWd.name}" rendered="#{keyWd.name != ''}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{keyWd.name}" required="true" requiredMessage="Enter a keyword!" placeholder="click here to edit" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Backing bean:

```
package test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.primefaces.event.CellEditEvent;
import test.entity.Keyword;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

    private List<Keyword> currentListKeywords = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addNewKeyword() {
        Keyword ap = new Keyword();
        ap.setName("");

        currentListKeywords.add(ap);
    }

    public void onCellEditKeywords(CellEditEvent event) {
        Object newWord = event.getNewValue();
//        LOG.info("newWord: " + newWord);

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Keyword currentWord = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{keyWd}", Keyword.class);

        if (newWord == null) {
            newWord = " ";
        }
        if (currentWord != null) {
            currentWord.setName((String) newWord);
        }
//        ejbFacade.editKeyword(currentWord);
    }

    public List<Keyword> getCurrentListKeywords() {
        return currentListKeywords;
    }

    public void setCurrentListKeywords(List<Keyword> currentListKeywords) {
        this.currentListKeywords = currentListKeywords;
    }
}
```

Finally the Keyword class:

```
package test.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Keyword implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    public Keyword(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Keyword() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I know the id of a JSF component so I can use in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045307/how-can-i-know-the-id-of-a-jsf-component-so-i-can-use-in-javascript)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201400/discussion-on-question-by-codyline-unable-to-set-focus-on-pinputtext-in-datatab).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I managed to solve this issue. Moving the `addNewKeyword` button in a separate form and removing `required` and `requiredMessage` attribute from the inputText solved the problem. I don't know why!?

```
    <h:form >
          <p:commandButton action="#{myBean.addNewKeyword}" oncomplete="setFocus();" value="New keyword" update='keywordForm' />
          <br /><br /><br/>
    </h:form>

    <h:form id="keywordForm" prependId="false" >

         <p:dataTable id="editKeywordsTbl" value="#{myBean.currentListKeywords}" var="keyWd" editMode="cell" editable="true" resizableColumns="true" widgetVar="editKeywords" rowIndexVar="index" >

            <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{myBean.onCellEditKeywords}" />

            <p:column headerText="Keyword" width="80">
                 <p:cellEditor>
                     <f:facet name="output">
                          <h:outputText value="[click me to edit]" rendered="#{keyWd.name == ''}" />
                          <h:outputText value="#{keyWd.name}" rendered="#{keyWd.name != ''}" />
                     </f:facet>
                     <f:facet name="input">
                          <p:inputText value="#{keyWd.name}" placeholder="click here to edit" />
                     </f:facet>
                 </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
   </h:form>
```

Thanks to everybody for the contribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with some js, in your button add a `oncomplete="selectFocus()"` and with a `p:remoteCommand` invoke your js code like this:

```
 <p:remoteCommand name="selectFocus" oncomplete="dataEditableFocus('dataTableWidgetVar', false);" />
```

your js must be like this:

```
dataEditableFocus = function (dataTableWidgetVar, hasRowIndex) {
    var row;
    var tb = $(document.getElementById(PF(dataTableWidgetVar).id));
    var multiple = $(tb).find('tr td.ui-selection-column');
    if ($(multiple).length === 0) {
        if (hasRowIndex) {
            row = $(tb).find('tr td.ui-editable-column:nth-child(2)');
        } else {
            row = $(tb).find('tr td.ui-editable-column:nth-child(1)');
        }
        $(row).last().find('input').click();
    } else {
        if (hasRowIndex) {
            row = $(tb).find('tr td.ui-editable-column:nth-child(3)');
        } else {
            row = $(tb).find('tr td.ui-editable-column:nth-child(2)');
        }
        $(row).last().parent().children().first().click();
        $(row).last().find('input').click();
    }
}
```

with this code if you add a row in your dataTable with `PF('dataTableWidgetVar').addRow()`
focus go on first element in editable datatable(if your table is `selectionMode="multiple"` ,code has some more complexy),you can edit code for focus on every element in datatable. if your elements have `RowIndex`, pass it true in invoke function(dierection of table maybe effect on code!).

Comment: It's not working. Same behaviour, the new inputText is opened for edit and has focus for a second and then get lost.

Comment: @codyLine Probably something in your code will effect. It is best to remove the extras and try again

Comment: I provided a minimal reproducable example. Please feel free to test your code on it. Will take less than 5 minutes.

Comment: @codyLine ok,if i'll can,i'll test it today

Comment: @codyLine if focus appears for a second i think it is for update datatable,you should not update datatable after focus.

Comment: Without update, the generated inputText will not appear in datatable.

Comment: @codyLine use `PF('dataTableWidgetVar').addRow()` for add row and don't use update for form or datatable in button.