# p:blockUI not getting shown when triggered from datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working on task to send sms and part of that I need to show a busy loader and I have tried primefaces p:blockUI which is not working at all. The block UI is not get shown when triggered from a datatable button row. Here is my code that is not working. I am using primefaces 5.3. Its like each button in the table is getting assigned its own unique id which means the id specified in the Ui block trigger isn't the one on the button row clicked.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

    <body>

        <ui:composition template="./template/template.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="pageTitle">
              Send Sms
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="pagecontent" id="blocker">

                <p:panel id="panel_sms" header="My Contacts">
              <p:blockUI block="panel_sms" id="wds" widgetVar="wds" trigger=":form1:tbl:btn_send_sms"  >
                                <p:graphicImage library="images" value="/img/3.gif"/> 
                                <br/>
                                <h:outputText value="Sending Sms Please wait...    " style="font-weight: bolder"/> 
                            </p:blockUI>


                <h:form id="form1">


                    <p:growl showDetail="true"/>


                    <p:dataTable rowKey="#{item.id}"  paginator="false" 
                                 rows="8"  
                                 editable="true"  widgetVar="table_route"
                                 id="tbl"
                                value="#{model.loadContacts}" var="item" >

                         <p:column style="width: 15%;">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Customer Name"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.name} "/> 
                        </p:column>
                          <p:column style="width: 15%;">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Contact"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.contact} "/> 
                        </p:column>                        

                        <p:column headerText="Send Sms"   style="width:8%;align-content: center">  
                            <center>
                                <p:commandButton id="btn_send_sms" update="form1"
                                style="background: #4a148c" value="Send Sms" icon="ui-icon-signal-diag" action="#{model.doLenthyTask(item)}"><--Have simulated a threaad to sleep 5 seconds-->

                                    <p:confirm message="Send Sms?"/>
                                </p:commandButton> 
                            </center>
                     </p:column> 

                    </p:dataTable>


                </h:form>

                               </p:panel>
            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </body>
```

But when I try trigger it in a button not in a datatable it works fine.

Comment: Please read https://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info about templates and [mcve]

Comment: @Kukeltje You dont understand my question?

Comment: Yes, but it should not include templates (effectively you now imply that it works if you don't use a template if this is your [mcve]. And for me to try to reproduce, I cannot. Copy/pasting this in an empty JSF + PrimeFaces project does not result in something that is runnable. You also miss versioninfo btw, and you forgot a PrimeFaces tag on the question. All just some hints for creating better questions (and also helping you narrow things down).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo)

Comment: @Kukeltje have updated my question and the issue is that the p:uiBlock not getting invoked by a button inside a table. Its like each button on each row its having its own unique id which does not reflect the id i specified as the trigger in the UiBlock

Comment: Correct... All default JSF behaviour. See my answer and read the first link in the see also (which I also propose as a duplicate, not sure it it is 100% so, but at least 90%)

Comment: @Kukeltje its not working for subsequent clicks only for first time    <p:commandButton id="btn_send_sms" update="form1" onstart="PF('wds').show()" oncomplete="PF('wds').hide()"
        style="background: #4a148c" value="Send Sms" icon="ui-icon-signal-diag" action="#{model.doLenthyTask(item)}"><--Have simulated a threaad to sleep 5 seconds-->
                            
                                    <p:confirm message="Send Sms?"/>
                                </p:commandButton>

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks alot the error is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no component client-side with an id of `:form1:tbl:btn_send_sms` to which you refer in your trigger.

The dataTable is a iterating component  which adds an "index" to the client-id, so if you inspect the buttons with a browser developer tool, for the buttons you'll see id's like

- `form1:tbl:1:btn_send_sms`
- `form1:tbl:2:btn_send_sms`
- `form1:tbl:3:btn_send_sms`

So you'll need to add something different in the trigger like a PrimeFaces selector (e.g. based on a class), or use the client-side api of the block ui in the `onStart` and `onComplete` attributes of the `commandButton` like `onStart="PF('wds').show()` and the corresponding hide

### See also

- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo)
- [How can I know the id of a JSF component so I can use in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045307/how-can-i-know-the-id-of-a-jsf-component-so-i-can-use-in-javascript)
- https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/blockui

Comment: it only works once. Eg if i click first row it works. when i click second row it does not show. My button looks this way now   <p:commandButton id="btn_send_sms" update="form1" onstart="PF('wds').show()" oncomplete="PF('wds').hide()"
        style="background: #4a148c" value="Send Sms" icon="ui-icon-signal-diag" action="#{model.doLenthyTask(item)}"><--Have simulated a threaad to sleep 5 seconds-->
                            
                                    <p:confirm message="Send Sms?"/>
                                </p:commandButton>

Answer (score 0):

You are not processing anything with that button. You need to put process"@this" or process"tableID" in command button.