# How to clear calendar input with java script

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

JavaScript function after clicking on clear button

```js
function resetTime() {
    document.getElementById("to_time").valueAsDate = null;
}
```

PrimeFaces calendar tag

```html
<p:calendar id="to_time"
            value="#{anomaliesList.toDate}"
            readonlyInput="true"
            maxdate="#{currentDate}"
            size="16"
            pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `p:calendar` is deprecated. Use `p:datePicker` instead.

The easiest way to deal with this is setting a `widgetVar` on your `p:datePicker`. This allows you to use the [client side API](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/jsdocs/classes/src_PrimeFaces.PrimeFaces.widget.DatePicker-1.html).

To reset a date, use:

```js
PF('yourWidgetName').setDate(null);
```

Note that if you want to use `getElementById` you probably need to incorporate the form clientId.

See also:

- [How can I know the id of a JSF component so I can use in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045307/how-can-i-know-the-id-of-a-jsf-component-so-i-can-use-in-javascript)